# How do I seal the bottom plate along my foundation?

Tags: foundation

I have a "steps" in the foundation where there are slim but visible openings to the outside. My questions are; How do I seal this? From the outside/inside? What product do I use?

[image]

Edit: Picture of complete wall

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The framing should have been installed with foam known as sill seal. If it wasn't, you could use any caulk such as silicone to seal against air and insect intrusion.

I'm a bit confused why I see drywall directly against masonry like that. Normally you have energy walls built inside the foundation, and the framing laps past on to the upper wall, such that the entire wall is adequately insulated and a vapor barrier is applied. The combination of all these things usually results in a completely sealed wall.

Comment: The drywall is inside on top of spray foam insulation.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. What's insulating the concrete wall?

Comment: nothing. the basement is not finished.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. You'd normally build energy walls that close things up.

Comment: Okay. Just to clarify. Drywall is not directly against masonry.

Comment: I didn't mean in physical contact. Normally it's not even in close proximity. [Here's an example](http://vybary.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/incredible-inspiration-framing-walls-re-basement-after-flooding-drain-tile-with-no-enter-image-description-here-in-on-concrete-101-corners-slab.jpg) of half-height energy wall framing.

Comment: i've updated my question with pic of full wall